# Is there any plugin available for displaying the version of a Maven project?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I need to display the version of a project (which is defined in pom.xml of the project) which running a package goal.
I tried using maven-version-plugin. It seems that, I can change the version using versions:set but,  can not display the current version of the project(mentioned in pom.xml) it while running a package on the console.

Is there any way to do it using a plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear. Do you want to print to the console the project version during package phase?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yeah, precisely I want to do so.